# set Country name and country code to button title text according to contact number extension i. +91 when fetched from contact list swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, list, contacts, country

I have a app in which i have a button whose title text displays country name and code when tapped on it. i.e it displays IN +91. when the button is pressed, a popup opens which lists all country with the country name and code. Now beside that beside i have a mobile number textfield which will display mobile number when selected from contact list. Beside mobile textfield i have a button which opens up default contact list, now what i want that let's say i have picked a contact whose number is +919998536042, then the number 9998536042 must be displayed on textfield and the button title text should display IN +91. i.e the extension from contact list must match up with the country code in countrylist array that i have used to display the country list. Please help me. I am stuck. and one more thing lets say i clicked on In +91 button and selected for example US +1, then i picked contact which doesn't have a extesnion then the button title text will remain same which is US +1 and if extension found for example +91 then some number then button title text will be IN +91

my app images for better understanding:
[image: screenshot 1]

now clicking on IN +91 opens up a picker shown in screenshot 2
[image: screenshot 2]

country data:

```
let Country:[[String:[String]]] = [["AF": ["Afghanistan","93"]],
                                   ["AX": ["Aland Islands","358"]],
                                   ["AL": ["Albania","355"]],
                                   ["DZ": ["Algeria","213"]],
                                   ["AS": ["American Samoa","1"]],
                                   ["AD": ["Andorra","376"]],
                                   ["AO": ["Angola","244"]],
                                   ["AI": ["Anguilla","1"]],
                                   ["AQ": ["Antarctica","672"]],
                                   ["AG": ["Antigua and Barbuda","1"]],
                                   ["AR": ["Argentina","54"]],
                                   ["AM": ["Armenia","374"]],
                                   ["AW": ["Aruba","297"]],
                                   ["AU": ["Australia","61"]],
                                   ["AT": ["Austria","43"]],
                                   ["AZ": ["Azerbaijan","994"]],
                                   ["BS": ["Bahamas","1"]],
                                   ["BH": ["Bahrain","973"]],
                                   ["BD": ["Bangladesh","880"]],
                                   ["BB": ["Barbados","1"]],
                                   ["BY": ["Belarus","375"]],
                                   ["BE": ["Belgium","32"]],
                                   ["BZ": ["Belize","501"]],
                                   ["BJ": ["Benin","229"]],
                                   ["BM": ["Bermuda","1"]],
                                   ["BT": ["Bhutan","975"]],
                                   ["BO": ["Bolivia","591"]],
                                   ["BA": ["Bosnia and Herzegovina","387"]],
                                   ["BW": ["Botswana","267"]],
                                   ["BV": ["Bouvet Island","47"]],
                                   ["BQ": ["BQ","599"]],
                                   ["BR": ["Brazil","55"]],
                                   ["IO": ["British Indian Ocean Territory","246"]],
                                   ["VG": ["British Virgin Islands","1"]],
                                   ["BN": ["Brunei Darussalam","673"]],
                                   ["BG": ["Bulgaria","359"]],
                                   ["BF": ["Burkina Faso","226"]],
                                   ["BI": ["Burundi","257"]],
                                   ["KH": ["Cambodia","855"]],
                                   ["CM": ["Cameroon","237"]],
                                   ["CA": ["Canada","1"]],
                                   ["CV": ["Cape Verde","238"]],
                                   ["KY": ["Cayman Islands","345"]],
                                   ["CF": ["Central African Republic","236"]],
                                   ["TD": ["Chad","235"]],
                                   ["CL": ["Chile","56"]],
                                   ["CN": ["China","86"]],
                                   ["CX": ["Christmas Island","61"]],
                                   ["CC": ["Cocos (Keeling) Islands","61"]],
                                   ["CO": ["Colombia","57"]],
                                   ["KM": ["Comoros","269"]],
                                   ["CG": ["Congo (Brazzaville)","242"]],
                                   ["CD": ["Congo, Democratic Republic of the","243"]],
                                   ["CK": ["Cook Islands","682"]],
                                   ["CR": ["Costa Rica","506"]],
                                   ["CI": ["Côte d'Ivoire","225"]],
                                   ["HR": ["Croatia","385"]],
                                   ["CU": ["Cuba","53"]],
                                   ["CW": ["Curacao","599"]],
                                   ["CY": ["Cyprus","537"]],
                                   ["CZ": ["Czech Republic","420"]],
                                   ["DK": ["Denmark","45"]],
                                   ["DJ": ["Djibouti","253"]],
                                   ["DM": ["Dominica","1"]],
                                   ["DO": ["Dominican Republic","1"]],
                                   ["EC": ["Ecuador","593"]],
                                   ["EG": ["Egypt","20"]],
                                   ["SV": ["El Salvador","503"]],
                                   ["GQ": ["Equatorial Guinea","240"]],
                                   ["ER": ["Eritrea","291"]],
                                   ["EE": ["Estonia","372"]],
                                   ["ET": ["Ethiopia","251"]],
                                   ["FK": ["Falkland Islands (Malvinas)","500"]],
                                   ["FO": ["Faroe Islands","298"]],
                                   ["FJ": ["Fiji","679"]],
                                   ["FI": ["Finland","358"]],
                                   ["FR": ["France","33"]],
                                   ["GF": ["French Guiana","594"]],
                                   ["PF": ["French Polynesia","689"]],
                                   ["TF": ["French Southern Territories","689"]],
                                   ["GA": ["Gabon","241"]],
                                   ["GM": ["Gambia","220"]],
                                   ["GE": ["Georgia","995"]],
                                   ["DE": ["Germany","49"]],
                                   ["GH": ["Ghana","233"]],
                                   ["GI": ["Gibraltar","350"]],
                                   ["GR": ["Greece","30"]],
                                   ["GL": ["Greenland","299"]],
                                   ["GD": ["Grenada","1"]],
                                   ["GP": ["Guadeloupe","590"]],
                                   ["GU": ["Guam","1"]],
                                   ["GT": ["Guatemala","502"]],
                                   ["GG": ["Guernsey","44"]],
                                   ["GN": ["Guinea","224"]],
                                   ["GW": ["Guinea-Bissau","245"]],
                                   ["GY": ["Guyana","595"]],
                                   ["HT": ["Haiti","509"]],
                                   ["VA": ["Holy See (Vatican City State)","379"]],
                                   ["HN": ["Honduras","504"]],
                                   ["HK": ["Hong Kong, Special Administrative Region of China","852"]],
                                   ["HU": ["Hungary","36"]],
                                   ["IS": ["Iceland","354"]],
                                   ["IN": ["India","91"]],
                                   ["ID": ["Indonesia","62"]],
                                   ["IR": ["Iran, Islamic Republic of","98"]],
                                   ["IQ": ["Iraq","964"]],
                                   ["IE": ["Ireland","353"]],
                                   ["IM": ["Isle of Man","44"]],
                                   ["IL": ["Israel","972"]],
                                   ["IT": ["Italy","39"]],
                                   ["JM": ["Jamaica","1"]],
                                   ["JP": ["Japan","81"]],
                                   ["JE": ["Jersey","44"]],
                                   ["JO": ["Jordan","962"]],
                                   ["KZ": ["Kazakhstan","77"]],
                                   ["KE": ["Kenya","254"]],
                                   ["KI": ["Kiribati","686"]],
                                   ["KP": ["Korea, Democratic People's Republic of","850"]],
                                   ["KR": ["Korea, Republic of","82"]],
                                   ["KW": ["Kuwait","965"]],
                                   ["KG": ["Kyrgyzstan","996"]],
                                   ["LA": ["Lao PDR","856"]],
                                   ["LV": ["Latvia","371"]],
                                   ["LB": ["Lebanon","961"]],
                                   ["LS": ["Lesotho","266"]],
                                   ["LR": ["Liberia","231"]],
                                   ["LY": ["Libya","218"]],
                                   ["LI": ["Liechtenstein","423"]],
                                   ["LT": ["Lithuania","370"]],
                                   ["LU": ["Luxembourg","352"]],
                                   ["MO": ["Macao, Special Administrative Region of China","853"]],
                                   ["MK": ["Macedonia, Republic of","389"]],
                                   ["MG": ["Madagascar","261"]],
                                   ["MW": ["Malawi","265"]],
                                   ["MY": ["Malaysia","60"]],
                                   ["MV": ["Maldives","960"]],
                                   ["ML": ["Mali","223"]],
                                   ["MT": ["Malta","356"]],
                                   [ "MH": ["Marshall Islands","692"]],
                                   ["MQ": ["Martinique","596"]],
                                   [ "MR": ["Mauritania","222"]],
                                   ["MU": ["Mauritius","230"]],
                                   [ "YT": ["Mayotte","262"]],
                                   ["MX": ["Mexico","52"]],
                                   [ "FM": ["Micronesia, Federated States of","691"]],
                                   ["MD": ["Moldova","373"]],
                                   [ "MC": ["Monaco","377"]],
                                   ["MN": ["Mongolia","976"]],
                                   [ "ME": ["Montenegro","382"]],
                                   ["MS": ["Montserrat","1"]],
                                   [ "MA": ["Morocco","212"]],
                                   ["MZ": ["Mozambique","258"]],
                                   [ "MM": ["Myanmar","95"]],
                                   ["NA": ["Namibia","264"]],
                                   [ "NR": ["Nauru","674"]],
                                   ["NP": ["Nepal","977"]],
                                   [ "NL": ["Netherlands","31"]],
                                   ["AN": ["Netherlands Antilles","599"]],
                                   [ "NC": ["New Caledonia","687"]],
                                   ["NZ": ["New Zealand","64"]],
                                   [ "NI": ["Nicaragua","505"]],
                                   ["NE": ["Niger","227"]],
                                   [ "NG": ["Nigeria","234"]],
                                   ["NU": ["Niue","683"]],
                                   [ "NF": ["Norfolk Island","672"]],
                                   ["MP": ["Northern Mariana Islands","1"]],
                                   [ "NO": ["Norway","47"]],
                                   ["OM": ["Oman","968"]],
                                   [ "PK": ["Pakistan","92"]],
                                   ["PW": ["Palau","680"]],
                                   [ "PS": ["Palestinian Territory, Occupied","970"]],
                                   ["PA": ["Panama","507"]],
                                   [ "PG": ["Papua New Guinea","675"]],
                                   ["PY": ["Paraguay","595"]],
                                   [ "PE": ["Peru","51"]],
                                   ["PH": ["Philippines","63"]],
                                   [ "PN": ["Pitcairn","872"]],
                                   ["PL": ["Poland","48"]],
                                   [ "PT": ["Portugal","351"]],
                                   ["PR": ["Puerto Rico","1"]],
                                   [ "QA": ["Qatar","974"]],
                                   ["RE": ["Réunion","262"]],
                                   [ "RO": ["Romania","40"]],
                                   ["RU": ["Russian Federation","7"]],
                                   [ "RW": ["Rwanda","250"]],
                                   ["SH": ["Saint Helena","290"]],
                                   [ "KN": ["Saint Kitts and Nevis","1"]],
                                   ["LC": ["Saint Lucia","1"]],
                                   ["PM": ["Saint Pierre and Miquelon","508"]],
                                   [ "VC": ["Saint Vincent and Grenadines","1"]],
                                   ["BL": ["Saint-Barthélemy","590"]],
                                   ["MF": ["Saint-Martin (French part)","590"]],
                                   [ "WS": ["Samoa","685"]],
                                   ["SM": ["San Marino","378"]],
                                   [ "ST": ["Sao Tome and Principe","239"]],
                                   ["SA": ["Saudi Arabia","966"]],
                                   [ "SN": ["Senegal","221"]],
                                   ["RS": ["Serbia","381"]],
                                   [ "SC": ["Seychelles","248"]],
                                   ["SL": ["Sierra Leone","232"]],
                                   ["SG": ["Singapore","65"]],
                                   [ "SX": ["Sint Maarten","1"]],
                                   ["SK": ["Slovakia","421"]],
                                   [ "SI": ["Slovenia","386"]],
                                   ["SB": ["Solomon Islands","677"]],
                                   [ "SO": ["Somalia","252"]],
                                   ["ZA": ["South Africa","27"]],
                                   [ "GS": ["South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands","500"]],
                                   ["SS​": ["South Sudan","211"]],
                                   [ "ES": ["Spain","34"]],
                                   ["LK": ["Sri Lanka","94"]],
                                   [ "SD": ["Sudan","249"]],
                                   [ "SR": ["Suriname","597"]],
                                   ["SJ": ["Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands","47"]],
                                   [ "SZ": ["Swaziland","268"]],
                                   [ "SE": ["Sweden","46"]],
                                   [ "CH": ["Switzerland","41"]],
                                   [ "SY": ["Syrian Arab Republic (Syria)","963"]],
                                   [ "TW": ["Taiwan, Republic of China","886"]],
                                   ["TJ": ["Tajikistan","992"]],
                                   [ "TZ": ["Tanzania, United Republic of","255"]],
                                   ["TH": ["Thailand","66"]],
                                   [ "TL": ["Timor-Leste","670"]],
                                   [ "TG": ["Togo","228"]],
                                   ["TK": ["Tokelau","690"]],
                                   ["TO": ["Tonga","676"]],
                                   [ "TT": ["Trinidad and Tobago","1"]],
                                   [ "TN": ["Tunisia","216"]],
                                   [ "TR": ["Turkey","90"]],
                                   [ "TM": ["Turkmenistan","993"]],
                                   [ "TC": ["Turks and Caicos Islands","1"]],
                                   [ "TV": ["Tuvalu","688"]],
                                   ["UG": ["Uganda","256"]],
                                   [ "UA": ["Ukraine","380"]],
                                   [ "AE": ["United Arab Emirates","971"]],
                                   ["GB": ["United Kingdom","44"]],
                                   ["US": ["United States of America","1"]],
                                   ["UY": ["Uruguay","598"]],
                                   ["UZ": ["Uzbekistan","998"]],
                                   ["VU": ["Vanuatu","678"]],
                                   ["VE": ["Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)","58"]],
                                   ["VN": ["Viet Nam","84"]],
                                   ["VI": ["Virgin Islands, US","1"]],
                                   ["WF": ["Wallis and Futuna Islands","681"]],
                                   ["EH": ["Western Sahara","212"]],
                                   ["YE": ["Yemen","967"]],
                                   ["ZM": ["Zambia","260"]],
                                   ["ZW": ["Zimbabwe","263"]]
]
```

My code for country list :

```
//Variables country popup
    var key = [String]()
    var value: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var c_name = [String]()
    var c_code = [String]()
    var searchTag = String()
    var select_code = String()
    var select_c_s_name = String()

override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        get_country_data()
    }

//MARK:- Fetch Country Data
    func get_country_data()
    {
        key.removeAll()
        value.removeAllObjects()
        for i in 0 ..< Country.count
        {
            let U = [String](Country[i].keys)
            let V =  Array(Country[i][U[0]]!)
            key.append(U[0])
            value.add(V)
        }
        c_name.removeAll()
        c_code.removeAll()
        for j in 0 ..< value.count
        {
            c_name.append((value.object(at: j) as! NSArray).object(at: 0) as! String)
            c_code.append((value.object(at: j) as! NSArray).object(at: 1) as! String)
        }
        self.cntryTblView.reloadData()
    }

    //MARK:- Country Code Search Functions
    func search_data()
    {
        let searchResult = Country.flatMap({ $0 }).filter {
            let variable = $0
            return variable.value[0].lowercased().contains(searchTag) || variable.value[1].lowercased().contains(searchTag) || variable.key.lowercased().contains(searchTag)
        }
        key.removeAll()
        value.removeAllObjects()
        for i in 0..<searchResult.count
        {
            key.append(searchResult[i].key)
            value.add(searchResult[i].value)
        }
        c_name.removeAll()
        c_code.removeAll()
        for j in 0..<value.count {
            c_name.append((value.object(at: j) as! NSArray).object(at: 0) as! String)
            c_code.append((value.object(at: j) as! NSArray).object(at: 1) as! String)
        }
        self.cntryTblView.reloadData()
    }

   @IBAction func selectCntryCode(_ sender: DCustomButton)
    {
       ApiUtillity.sharedInstance.AddSubViewtoParentView(parentview: self.view, subview: self.cntryPopupView)

    }

extension NeighbourDetailsVC: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return key.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CountryCodeCell", for: indexPath) as! CountryCodeCell
            cell.cntry_img.image = UIImage(named: key[indexPath.row])
            cell.cntry_code.text = "+"+c_code[indexPath.row]
            cell.cntry_name.text = c_name[indexPath.row]+"  "+"("+key[indexPath.row]+")"
            return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        select_code = c_code[indexPath.row]
        select_c_s_name = key[indexPath.row]
        self.cntryTblView.reloadData()
        self.countryCodeBtn.setTitle(select_c_s_name+" +"+select_code, for: .normal)
        self.get_country_data()
    }
}
```

Code for when tapping on button which opens up contact list picker:

```
//MARK:- Open Contact Picker
    @IBAction func openContactPicker(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        askForContactAccess()
    }

//MARK:- Ask for contact access
    func askForContactAccess()
    {
        let authorizationStatus = CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: CNEntityType.contacts)

        switch authorizationStatus
        {
        case .denied, .notDetermined:
            self.contactStore.requestAccess(for: CNEntityType.contacts, completionHandler: { (access, accessError) -> Void in
                if !access {
                    if authorizationStatus == CNAuthorizationStatus.denied {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let message = "\(accessError!.localizedDescription)\n\nPlease allow the app to access your contacts through the Settings."
                            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Contacts", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

                            let dismissAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { (action) -> Void in
                            }

                            alertController.addAction(dismissAction)

                            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            break
        case .authorized:
            contactPicker.delegate = self
            contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactMiddleNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
            self.present(contactPicker, animated: true)
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }

// Delegate method for contact picker in which i am setting selected contact name and number to name and mobile textfield
extension NeighbourDetailsVC: CNContactPickerDelegate
{
    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact)
    {
        let phoneNumbersCount = contact.phoneNumbers.count
        let userName: String = "\(contact.givenName) \(contact.middleName) \(contact.familyName)"

        guard phoneNumbersCount > 0 else
        {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Selected contact doesn't have a number", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: {
                alert -> Void in

            })
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            dismiss(animated: true)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        if phoneNumbersCount == 1
        {
           setNumberFromContact(contactNumber: contact.phoneNumbers[0].value.stringValue)
           self.nameTxtField.text = userName
        }
        else
        {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Select one of the numbers", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

            for i in 0...phoneNumbersCount-1
            {
                let phoneAction = UIAlertAction(title: contact.phoneNumbers[i].value.stringValue, style: .default, handler: {
                    alert -> Void in
                    self.setNumberFromContact(contactNumber: contact.phoneNumbers[i].value.stringValue)
                    self.nameTxtField.text = userName
                })
                alertController.addAction(phoneAction)
            }
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: {
                alert -> Void in

            })
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

            dismiss(animated: true)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func setNumberFromContact(contactNumber: String)
    {
        var contactNumber = contactNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
        contactNumber = contactNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "")
        contactNumber = contactNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

        guard contactNumber.count >= 10 else
        {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Selected contact doesn't have a valid number", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: {
                alert -> Void in

            })
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            dismiss(animated: true)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        self.mobileTxtField.text = String(contactNumber.suffix(10))
        self.mobileTxtField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: So what did you try and what didn't work when you tried that?

Comment: Actually Kiril S., the name and contact are being displayed on the name textfield and mobile textfield when contact is selected but the button title text not being set according to the extension . This project i received today from another guy who has done this code, my task is to set the mobile number selected to mobile textfield which i did but this part i am not getting it

Comment: Please somebody help me